# Mysql join get one row per match

Tags: mysql, join

I have a mysql query with a join and I want for each match to get one only row not all. What I mean.

for example we have the two tables

```
ids(int id)
colors(int id, varchar color)
```

I have the query

```
select ids.id, colors.color from ids join colors on ids.id = colors.id;
```

and get the following

```
id | color
------------------
1  | red 
1  | blue 
2  | yellow 
3  | green 
3  | pink
```

I want a query to get the

```
id | color 
-----------------
1  | red 
2  | yellow 
3  | green
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using a subquery which limits the amount of results:

```
select ids.id, (select colors.color WHERE colors.id = ids.id LIMIT 1) AS color FROM ids;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
  ids.id, 
  min(colors.color) as color
from 
  ids 
join 
  colors on ids.id = colors.id
group by
  ids.id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

`select ids.id, colors.color from ids join colors on ids.id = colors.id group by ids.id;`

But remember: you get an **unguaranteed** value for `colors.color`.

Comment: On additional note, if Group By is applied here, what happens to non Numeric data type. It returns a random value? In numeric, we can obtain SUM, average etc.

Comment: @shamim From [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html):

_The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are **indeterminate**. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses._

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ids.id, colors.color FROM ids JOIN colors ON ids.id = colors.id GROUP BY ids.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies, all of you said me to use the *group by* Of course this method was the first that I tried, but I get the below error:

> Column "COLORS.COLOR" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:

My query is the

```
SELECT 
    ids.id, colors.color 
FROM ids 
     JOIN colors ON ids.id = colors.id 
GROUP BY ids.id;
```

*Also, I must say you that I use the h2database*